# How to ensure complete handoff of my Magento site from third-party developer

Tags: magento

I have had a third-party developer install & custom code a magento site for me. What are things I must take care of to ensure I can run the site independently of him. I understand its important to have my email as the admin user, get the encryption key etc.

What else is important here?

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: In addition to what benmarks said, I would strongly recommend a version control system and frequent backups. That way if something does indeed go wrong, it's a matter of reverting changes or pulling a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Access to your hosting account is all you need, as it will give you acces to your files and database.

Comment: You may wanna check for unknown OUTGOING connections to ensure that the developer didn't leave code that may send information to the developer in the code, but most legitimate developers won't do this.  This is usually reserved for code updates, and RSS messages.

Comment: Thanks. To Vern's point, how do i check for outgoing connections in the code? Also to complete the handoff, I changed the FTP passwords, as also the database password in the app/etc/local.xml file. The site went down. The developer is not helping here at all. So I changed the password back to the original & the site is up. Is this a cache issue & how do I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: The database password issue is resolved. It had to do with some characters in the password that the system objected to.